# Python P2P messaging

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

So the goal of this is code is to have a point to point connection. One client will host the connection and the other will just connect and they should be able to talk back and forth freely. I am trying to write the code myself, but I'm new to socket programming, and threading. I don't really want to to use a library that does all of the networking for me just yet. Any ideas to push me in the right direction? Can I have two threads communicate on the same port? I appreciate the input.

To test this you would have to run two instances, the first terminal will take an input(choose "S" for server) and the second, type anything(or nothing) to act as the client side. I am testing this code to incorporate it into a larger program I am working on, so the finished product will be more user friendly!

I'm running into the following errors:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 11, in recvthread
    data = client.recv(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Here is the code trying to incorporate threading:

```
import socket
import threading
from threading import Thread
import select
import sys

def recvthread(mssg):
    print mssg
    if (mssg == 1):
        while True:
            data = client.recv(size)
            print "[Other]:" + data
    if (mssg == 2):
        while True:
            data = s.recv(size)
            print "[Other]:" + data

def sendthread(mssg):
    print mssg
    if (mssg == 1):
        while True:
            data = raw_input("[ME]>")
            client.send(data)
    if (mssg == 2):
        while True:
            data = raw_input("[ME]>")
            s.send(data)

host = 'localhost'
port = 2000
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
x = raw_input()
test = 'S'
if (x == test):
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    client, address = s.accept()
    t1 = Thread(target=recvthread, args=(1,))
    t2 = Thread(target=sendthread, args=(1,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    client.close()
else:
    s.connect((host, port))
    t1 = Thread(target=recvthread, args=(2,))
    t2 = Thread(target=sendthread, args=(2,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
s.close()
```

Comment: `client.close()` just after starting the threads? What could it possibly result in?

Comment: wouldn't it wait until the threads finished before moving to that part of the code or does it just move on? so should I create a list of threads and use a t.join() to wait for them to finish?

Comment: Exactly. Your threads never finish as they are now though.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I did know about the never-ending loop. This code is just proof of concept for a larger project that I am working on. The finished product will have some way of detecting if the socket is broken or a way for the user to close the connection. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was me not completely understanding the threading. If I wanted the code to wait for the threads to wait I needed to use join(). Rookie mistake... Thanks for the help!